# how to create git merge driver that selects the latest commited file

Tags: git

I want to build a git merge driver that automatically selects the latest commited file in any conflict

from thew driver API i get the content of the file - but how do i get when each version was commited?

the content of the file can not help me (i do not want to place dates in the files as i generate them - since this will mean a new commit each time the file is generated - and not each time the content is changed)
the origin of the file does not help me since the latest version can come both from mine & theirs side of every merge
and the size of the file does not help either - since the content can change

Comment: It may be helpful to post the code you already have

Comment: @CharlesB i don't have a code just yet - i started and then i hit the wall of not knowing what commit each file came from. I get in my driver 3 temp files: each with the content to consider. but i am not interested in the content - i am interested in the commits those files came from

Answer (score 0):

```
git merge --ours
```

provide same functionality.

Comment: not it doesn't - as i wrote - the latest commit can come both from mine and from ours - so it does NOT solve the issue
here is one scenarioe: branch1 & branch2 both start from the same commit, both make commits in their own time. Then a merge can come from b1 to b2 and from b2 to b1 - in both cases i want to resolve the same: by using the content that was commited LAST